Comparing data at different locations over a time series
I have water quality data from sondes placed at different locations across a lake that collected every hour over the entirety of the summer. I want to know if there is a difference between the four locations for a parameter I collected. I also want to know when during the summer the biggest differences were seen. I do not know what statistical test I can run to investigate these two questions. I have plotted the time series data but that only gives a qualitative analysis.
Based on brief searches I have seen that a repeated measures ANOVA may work because the data is all paired with timestamps, but then I also saw Generalized Linear Models, or other models such as AIRMA models may be better. I am not as familiar with the models so I was unsure whether those fit my data appropriately or how they are used.
Any advice with how to handle this data is appreciated.

This sounds like a situation that needs such exploration rather than a formal testing situation.  How exactly is plotting only qualitative?
